WPF NavigationViewItem unwanted empty popup/flyout
I have a WPF application which implements a NavigationView using the ModernWPF toolkit. The Navigation view menu comprises of three items, each with icon and selection text, as you would expect, and a hamburger button to expand and contract the side pane. The problem I have is when the side pane is in the closed state and I select an menu item icon. I get an unwanted empty popup appearing until I click somewhere else. I think this might be an empty flyout.
<Window x:Class="My.App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ui="http://schemas.modernwpf.com/2019"
        xmlns:md="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        xmlns:rx="http://reactiveui.net"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.App"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ui:ThemeManager.RequestedTheme="Dark"
        Title="My-App" Height="720" Width="1080">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!--  Navigation menu item  -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NavigationViewMenuItem">
            <ui:NavigationViewItem
                Content="{Binding Title}"
                Icon="{Binding Icon}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding Selectable}"
                MenuItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
                SelectsOnInvoked="{Binding Selectable}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!--  Navigation header item  -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NavigationViewHeaderItem">
            <ui:NavigationViewItemHeader Content="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <!--  Template selector for navigation items  -->
        <local:NavigationTemplateSelector
            x:Key="NavigationTemplateSelector"
            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource NavigationViewHeaderItem}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NavigationViewMenuItem}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid UseLayoutRounding="True">
        <ui:NavigationView
            x:Name="NavigationView"
            AlwaysShowHeader="True"
            Grid.Row="0"
            IsPaneOpen="False"
            OpenPaneLength="150"
            IsSettingsVisible="False"
            IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
            IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="true"
            ItemInvoked="NavigationView_ItemInvoked"
            MenuItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource NavigationTemplateSelector}">
            <rx:RoutedViewHost
                x:Name="MainHost"
                Duration="0"
                ToolTip="{x:Null}"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ui:NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Window>

There is no such popup appearing when the navigation pane is in the open state.
If the popup is a flyout, could someone please help to disable it, or advise some other solution.
I have included the XAML code only for observation, as I don't think the code behind will offer anything else, however, please let me know if this is not enough to illustrate the problem.
Edit:
I realise that this problem might relate specifically to the ModernWPF toolkit, however, perhaps someone might be able to provide ideas of where to look to resolve the issue.
Thanks.

In terms of "where to start"; start with a "default implementation". Maybe it's trying to show any "empty" Tooltip when it shouldn't; e.g. setting said Tooltip to "null" does what?

Well, with given code it's not clearly reproducible. I refered the code from sample app provided by 'ModernWPF' and tried to create sample with your code.
Can you provide code for NavigationTemplateSelector and how you are adding menu items ?
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ui="http://schemas.modernwpf.com/2019"
    xmlns:md="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:rx="http://reactiveui.net"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
    ui:WindowHelper.UseModernWindowStyle="True"
    ui:ThemeManager.RequestedTheme="Dark"
    Title="WPF Toolbox Example" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <!--  Navigation menu item  -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NavigationViewMenuItem">
        <ui:NavigationViewItem
            Content="{Binding Title}"
            Icon="{Binding Icon}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Selectable}"
            MenuItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
            SelectsOnInvoked="{Binding Selectable}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <!--  Navigation header item  -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NavigationViewHeaderItem">
        <ui:NavigationViewItemHeader Content="{Binding Title}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <!--  Template selector for navigation items  -->
    <local:NavigationTemplateSelector
        x:Key="NavigationTemplateSelector"
        HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource NavigationViewHeaderItem}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NavigationViewMenuItem}" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <ui:NavigationView
        x:Name="NavigationView"
        AlwaysShowHeader="True"
        Grid.Row="0"
        IsPaneOpen="False"
        OpenPaneLength="150"
        IsSettingsVisible="False"
        IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
        IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="true"
        ItemInvoked="NavigationView_ItemInvoked"

        >
        <ui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <ui:NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item1" Tag="SamplePage1" Icon="Play" >
                <ui:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                    <ui:NavigationViewItem Content="Mail" Icon="Mail" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Mail" Tag="SamplePage3"/>
                    <ui:NavigationViewItem Content="Calendar" Icon="Calendar" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Calendar" Tag="SamplePage4"/>
                </ui:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
            </ui:NavigationViewItem>
            <ui:NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item2" Tag="SamplePage2" Icon="Save" />
            <ui:NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item3" Tag="SamplePage3" Icon="Refresh" />
            <ui:NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item4" Tag="SamplePage4" Icon="Download" />
        </ui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <rx:RoutedViewHost
            x:Name="MainHost"
            Duration="0"
            ToolTip="{x:Null}"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        
    </ui:NavigationView>
</Grid>


Thanks for your response. I resolved the issue, which was due to the MenuItemsSource binding. The problem was that the Children property was initialised to be an empty observable collection. This was causing an empty popup to represent as a placeholder for child menu items. Setting this to null fixed this.
